# How do i fix Out of Range message i get in Unity

Tags: c#

I have this code and I keep getting the error message

> Argument is out of range

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXjRR1nnC5M) and I have been following it exactly. I went back and checked everything but I am still getting the message.

**Here is my code:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogSystem : MonoBehaviour {
public static DialogSystem Instance { get; set; }
public GameObject dialogPanel;
public string npcname;
public List<string> dialoglines = new List<string> ();

Button continueButton;
Text dialogText, nameText;
int dialogIndex;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    continueButton = dialogPanel.transform.Find 
("Continue").GetComponent<Button> ();

    continueButton.onClick.AddListener (delegate {  ContinueDialog(); });
    dialogText = dialogPanel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    nameText = 
dialogPanel.transform.Find("Name").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
    dialogPanel.SetActive(false);



    if (Instance != null && Instance != this) {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}

public void addNewDialog(string[] lines, string npcname)
{
    dialogIndex = 0;
    dialoglines = new List<string>(lines.Length);
    dialoglines.AddRange (lines);
    this.npcname = npcname;

    Debug.Log (dialoglines.Count);
    CreatDialog ();
}

public void CreatDialog()
{
    dialogText.text = dialoglines [dialogIndex];
    nameText.text = npcname;
    dialogPanel.SetActive (true);
}


public void ContinueDialog()
{
    if (dialogIndex < dialoglines.Count - 1) {
        dialogIndex++;
        dialogText.text = dialoglines [dialogIndex];
    } 
    else 
    {
        dialogPanel.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

I have no idea and I am getting pretty far into my work and I am a new developer and I am struggling to figure this out on my own. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you are a new software developer my biggest advice to you is to google any errors you run into. 

`Argument is out of range` typically means that you are trying to read an index of an array that doesn't exist (your array has 4 values and you are trying to access the 5th value) in your code I would add some debugging code to the console to see where the code is being broken. Or if you know how I would use breakpoints instead.

Comment: i don"t know what most of that means and i have already tried to google it thank you for trying though.

Comment: This video covers what an array is: https://youtu.be/KcZM1Ls_Pn4 the error you are getting is because you are trying to access an index greater than the maximum number of indexes in that array EXAMPLE: Idx:0 - Val:A, Idx:1 - Val:B, Idx:2 - Val:C
If you were to access a value from that array at index (idx) 3 there is no value there so it throws the exception `Argument is out of range`. However, if you were to ask for index 2 it would return the value "C" perfectly fine

Comment: I think either `dialoglines = new List<string>(lines.Length);` or `nameText = 
dialogPanel.transform.Find("Name").GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
    dialogPanel.SetActive(false);` will be the culprit of your error.